# Attempting a FindAll with C# MongoDB driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm attempting a "find all" query using the latest version of the C# MongoDB driver.

The code looks a bit like this

```
var xx = _context.NLMCDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Requestables").Find<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument());
var qq = xx.ToListAsync<BsonDocument>();
long yy = await xx.CountAsync();
```

The database connection is fine I use the same connection for inserting data.
I have sent an empty query as

```
new BsonDocument()
```

The code executes but does not seem to return any results. When exploring with the debugger it reports

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit murky. Why do you have the `qq = xx.ToListAsync<BsonDocument>();` in there? I imagine it will receive the query result, leaving the next `yy = await ...` waiting forever? Given that `qq` will be a `List<BsonDocument>`, simply do `yy = qq.Count;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the await for the `xx.ToListAsync<BsonDocument>();` which means the value of `qq` will just be a task.

Try either:

```
var xx = _context.NLMCDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Requestables").Find<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument());
var qq = await xx.ToListAsync<BsonDocument>();
long yy = await xx.CountAsync();
```

or

```
var xx = _context.NLMCDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Requestables").Find<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument());
var qq = xx.ToListAsync<BsonDocument>();
long yy = await xx.CountAsync();
var listOfResults = await qq;
```